# How to add a dynamically generated JSON Schema to a current document in a visual studio code extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsonschema

I would like to generate a JSON schema dynamically at runtime in a visual studio code extension.

For example like that, the original would be generated, this is just a static example.

```
 const schema = new JsonSchema();
 schema.addSchemaProperty('packages', {
        type: 'array',
        items: {
          type: 'object',
          properties: {
            name: { type: 'string' },
            tasks: {
              type: 'array',
              items: {
                type: 'object',
                properties: {
                  Data: {
                    type: 'array',
                    items: {
                      type: 'object',
                      properties: {
                        attributeName: {
                          type: 'string',
                          enum: ['1', '2'], // Add enum with values 1 and 2
                        },
                        flow: { type: 'string' },
                        visibility: { type: 'string' },
                      },
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      });
```

Now I would like to apply the schema to the current document.

```
      const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
      if (!editor || editor.document.languageId !== 'json') {
        vscode.window.showErrorMessage('Please open a JSON document first');
        return;
      }
      const document = editor.document;
      const uri = document.uri.toString();
```

Unfortunately I fail to apply the JSONSchema to the document.

What I have in mind is something like that (not working code)

```
 vscode.languages.registerJSONSchemaProvider(languageId, schemaProvider);
 languageService.setSchema(uri, schema);
```

Thanks for pointing me into the right direction.

Comment: Just as comment because not a real answer to your question, JSONBuddy (https://www.json-buddy.com) generates a JSON Schema on the fly for any JSON data with no schema already assigned.

Comment: @Clemens I noticed you're the author of what you're promoting, but you didn't disclose affiliation. See also [/help/promotion](/help/promotion).

Comment: @user True, I read the page and will clarify this in future comments/answers.